# winston file transport issue

Tags: javascript, logging, winston

I'm trying to use winston logger, but it seems to have a strange behavior when used with the file transport. Perhaps it's something I'm missing and I couldn't figure it out.
I created a simple example to illustrate the issue. It uses the mocha for testing.

```
var log = require('winston')
log.add(log.transports.File, { filename: 'output.log' });

describe('Logger', function() {
        it('should save the 1st message', function(done) {
            log.info('1: this is the 1st message', function() {
                console.log('done 1')
                done()
            })
        })
        it('should save the 2nd message', function(done) {
            console.log('before test 2')
            log.info('2: this is the 2nd message', function() {
                console.log('done 2')
                done()
            })
        })
        it('should save the 3rd message', function(done) {
            log.info('3: this is the 3rd message', function() {
                console.log('done 3')
                done()
            })
        })
    }
)
```

The first message is saved in the output.log file, but not the other ones. Actually, only the callback of the 1st test is called. The `'before test 2'` is printed, but `'done 2'` isn't... and the 2nd message is not saved either.

But, when I comment the second line (`log.add(log.transports.File,...`), it behaves normally, showing in the console all the messages. Am I am missing something or is it a bug?

The winston version I'm using is 0.7.1.

Thanks in advance.

ps: the `console.log` was just for testing the test ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i got exactly the same problem. this is obviously a strange side effect with mocha and winston file loggging.

if have done the following test and replaced the global describe and it functions with my own functions:

```
  describe = function(name, func) {
    return func();
  };

  it = function(name, func) {
    return func(function() {});
  };
```

and then execute the test function directly with node. in this case the winston output is like expected. when executing the same test file with mocha again, you have the missing log entries again.

it seems like winston file flush is not triggered when executed with mocha.